# Log-normal model of data with unknown offset

Tags: maximum-likelihood, fitting, lognormal-distribution

I have a bunch of samples that, empirically speaking, appear to be drawn from an unknown log-normal distribution, with an unknown constant offset applied to the data points. That is, $\ln(X_{i} + C) \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$, assuming I remember my terminology.

(Actually, I have a bunch of bunches of samples.)

Given the method this data was collected with, this model appears plausible. And a naive empirical fit of said model appears to fit the data well enough.

The above being said, I am not a statistician.

Is this a sane model, generally speaking? (I am aware that a specific answer can't be had without details of the data & methods used.) If it is, is there a MLE for this? If there isn't, is there a more appropriate model to use (if so, which?)

Ditto, is there a name for this sort of model?

An example sample (inline, because I don't like link rot):

```
-8.21 -7.87 -0.56 -1.73 -9.36 -4.99 -6.97 -7.37 -8.79 -9.12 -7.01 -4.82 -9.63 -8.22 -3.75 -6.49 -7.85 -5.38 -5.79 -2.01 -7.41 -1.29 -6.44 -3.34 -6.11 -9.10 -6.54 -8.09 -2.41 -4.39 -4.99 -7.07 -5.34 -4.13 -4.86 2.07 -5.07 -6.90 -6.53 -6.46 -2.16 -5.85 -6.02 -0.96 -3.75 -7.58 -8.93 -8.53 -5.95 -4.16 -5.95 -9.24 -6.59 -6.04 -7.47 -6.73 -7.17 -8.76 -6.57 -8.42 -8.17 -6.01 2.88 0.88 -5.70 -5.66 -5.46 -7.26 -0.98 -6.15 -8.73 -4.11 -0.91 -9.54 -3.64 -8.67 -6.19 -7.25 -6.28 -6.74 -8.99 -5.29 -7.55 -6.85 -7.39 -8.65 -6.33 -8.77 -7.19 -4.37 -8.14 -6.47 -7.57 -7.51 -6.39 -9.55 -6.90 -4.00 -5.36 -8.94 -6.88 -6.74 -5.80 -5.19 -5.94 -7.82 -6.36 -1.77 -1.52 -6.29 -7.27 -9.28 -7.65 -7.64 -4.81 -1.44 -4.63 -4.84 -8.19 -7.65 -6.57 -4.07 -8.40 -8.06 -7.25 -3.48 -9.15 -7.43 -6.92 -6.81 -6.94 -6.11 -4.88 -6.81 -4.14 -8.63 -1.97 -7.40 -5.80 -8.37 -2.96 0.57 -3.54 -7.81 -5.54 0.06 -6.33 -8.39 -6.94 -7.16 -0.83 -5.77 -5.40 -6.82 -4.03 -8.25 -9.62 -7.33 -8.54 -5.07 -8.46 -5.21 -7.21 -7.52 -2.47 -8.46 -3.51 -5.95 -3.08 -8.48 -7.86 -3.15 -3.41 -7.08 -6.95 -0.23 -6.91 -7.82 -8.73 -1.39 -8.51 -6.21 -4.23 2.42 -5.79 -6.46 -6.88 -6.65 -9.76 -7.20 -3.33 -7.57 -7.67 -4.74 -4.85 -7.16 -4.80 -9.08 -8.41 -5.71 -5.89 -7.81 -7.97 -9.14 -9.71 -7.37 -6.95 -5.27 -2.37 -3.78 -6.68 -4.44 -7.67 -6.96 -8.46 -7.21 -2.81 -2.23 -5.23 -6.39 -5.42 -7.67 -5.71 -8.08 -3.54 -9.46 -8.82 -9.79 -6.84 -5.89 -8.65 -5.76 -3.44 -9.95 1.25 -8.33 -4.32 4.66 -5.86 -6.66 -8.02 -8.12 -7.89 -6.64 -7.25 -7.88 -6.31 -7.53 -7.56 -7.02 -7.80 -7.44 -5.48 -5.79 -6.82 -1.94 -5.11 -8.51 -4.49 -8.91 -7.31 -5.82 -6.62 -8.43 -3.52 -6.19 -2.72 -5.88 -7.27 -8.41 -7.48 -8.49 -8.44 -8.33 -4.24 -6.77 -7.82 -5.55 -9.73 -4.70 -7.22 -2.33 -7.13 -3.83 -4.32 -6.13 -5.63 -6.91 -7.49 -7.58 -7.02 -4.74 -7.75 -9.31 -5.07 -7.80 -9.56 -0.48 1.02 -5.54 -2.71 -6.07 -2.01 -7.23 -5.10 -9.09 -8.18 -7.89 -9.19 -3.04 -8.16 -2.04 -8.51 -7.25 3.20 -3.20 -6.45 -8.70 -9.08 -5.90 -5.43 -7.17 -7.31 -3.88 -8.46 -5.64 -1.60 -6.01 -6.81 -6.25 -4.81 -8.34 -7.32 -9.03 -5.94 -5.78 -8.74 -6.12 -7.51 -3.92 -8.89 -8.78 -2.85 -6.76 -4.94 -4.33 -5.48 -4.86 -5.62 -5.62 -4.93 -9.58 -8.75 -6.95 -2.97 -4.76 -8.04 -7.82 -3.07 -6.52 -8.31 -8.93 -7.03 -9.06 -8.87 -8.83 -6.57 0.13 -8.42 -5.90 -7.15 -6.14 -8.39 -3.66 -6.50 -8.81 -6.74 -4.71 -7.31 -9.42 -8.53 -5.17 -4.68 -9.29 -7.29 -9.27 -4.87 -2.81 -7.25 -2.31 -7.29 -6.43 -7.34 2.41 -8.26 -3.70 -7.01 -8.57 -4.25 -6.03 -7.87 -7.80 -2.97 -5.61 -6.94 -7.11 -8.92 -6.79 -0.67 -7.78 -4.02 -7.81 -6.16 -7.40 -9.46 -8.62 -7.14 -4.12 -8.40 -2.20 -8.58 -3.16 -8.44 -8.98 -9.16 -6.11 -7.83 -4.60 -7.04 -6.52 -7.38 -6.03 -6.18 -5.90 -4.99 -9.09 1.53 -0.42 -7.54 -8.41 -3.17 -4.66 -4.00 -8.88 -10.21 -8.54 -8.11 1.33 -6.36 -5.63 -6.51 -2.17 -8.79 -7.75 -5.83 -1.42 -4.55 -8.11 -6.70 -8.37 -8.44 -5.79 -6.46 -6.19 -7.57 -8.09 -7.44 -7.43 -7.77 -6.19 -8.19 -9.84 -3.91 -5.36 -8.35 -6.74 -5.33 -7.97 -2.41 -8.15 -7.61 -7.09 -7.88 -5.54 -3.84 -5.81 -10.10 -7.84 -5.44 -2.94 -5.44 -8.82 -5.61 -7.79 0.12 -6.90 -0.89 -8.12 -8.07 -2.20 0.28 -6.24 -6.19 -4.92 -7.77 -8.82 -6.79 -5.12 -3.95 -6.43 -7.89 -6.41 -7.04 -8.68 -5.18 -1.56 -7.29 -8.59 -8.01 -9.01 -9.12 -0.86 -4.11 -7.18 -6.91 -4.85 -8.30 -6.79 -6.83 -8.09 -7.58 -5.93 -7.54 -5.60 -7.58 -7.49 -3.96 7.04 -6.38 -7.44 -7.18 -6.05 -7.15 -6.03 -5.45 -6.14 -7.75 -6.99 -4.98 -5.96 -9.38 -8.28 -5.68 -7.48 -8.41 -7.79 -2.81 -6.65 -4.30 -5.57 -0.90 -6.06 -6.88 -7.34 -9.71 -5.64 -5.18 -7.05 -7.96 -6.47 -3.15 -3.53 -2.52 -4.59 -2.24 0.70 -6.99 -1.38 -6.39 -3.80 -8.43 -5.27 -8.30 -3.20 -3.99 -4.05 -5.76 -4.03 -8.15 -3.09 -6.98 -9.70 -4.14 -8.54 -5.74 0.80 -3.33 -3.25 -6.13 -6.68 -1.82 -1.42 -8.15 -6.07 -7.89 -7.41 -9.22 -8.01 -4.02 -6.13 1.24 -5.72 -6.53 -5.00 -4.51 -6.36 -7.19 -8.03 0.75 -6.03 -6.65 -5.62 -4.82 -1.91 -8.05 -8.45 -2.02 -5.90 -7.33 -7.89 -7.95 -4.97 -3.30 -8.62 -7.40 -7.29 3.15 -2.97 -5.95 -3.61 -4.66 -4.52 -7.18 -8.67 -7.28 -3.95 -5.24 -8.34 -9.45 -5.46 -8.92 -3.54 -5.30 -7.85 -9.30 -6.69 -5.54 -7.46 -7.15 -6.34 -8.73 -5.20 -8.84 -9.63 0.44 -9.00 -5.02 -6.04 -4.15 -7.90 -7.24 -4.32 -2.50 -4.70 -6.87 -6.54 2.20 -8.62 -5.95 -3.48 -1.95 -7.18 -7.71 -6.25 -8.56 -3.42 -4.95 -7.14 -8.42 -7.53 -2.72 -7.10 -6.68 -8.17 -2.78 -6.92 -7.63 -7.58 0.49 -6.64 -4.53 -4.79 -7.40 -8.21 -6.98 -7.38 -8.08 -6.26 -6.93 -6.91 -8.55 -7.14 -9.87 -8.45 -4.15 -7.87 -6.14 -6.69 -5.73 0.59 -5.08 -8.38 -7.24 -1.38 -8.39 -5.40 -6.52 -3.56 -4.52 -6.08 -7.65 -7.34 -3.02 -6.62 -2.22 -0.01 -6.13 -5.93 -8.09 -9.20 -4.36 -7.58 -5.88 -2.92 -7.39 -3.54 -7.98 -7.88 -0.42 2.88 -5.54 -8.06 -5.76 -8.76 -5.93 -8.29 -7.52 -8.24 -7.96 -8.99 -8.82 -5.07 -6.45 0.95 -0.38 -4.01 -7.63 -9.12 -8.05 -4.00 -6.92 -8.37 -5.98 -6.41 -7.32 -7.63 -7.33 -5.97 -7.70 -4.09 -3.25 -0.68 -0.91 -7.69 -4.52 -8.27 -6.96 -8.32 -2.93 -3.52 -5.71 -9.13 -6.99 1.62 -5.20 -8.83 -5.03 -7.14 -8.67 -4.48 -6.94 -1.49 -4.99 -8.00 -7.12 -8.71 -8.11 -2.68 -9.02 -7.46 -0.22 -7.82 -6.28 -10.01 -4.82 -5.25 -4.52 -8.61 -8.30 -5.92 -4.22 -8.99 -6.96 -3.36 -9.76 -8.52 -7.33 -8.25 -0.32 -8.36 -5.59 -5.61 -7.67 -8.42 -6.64 -8.86 -8.55 -7.55 -4.13 -8.14 -7.68 -9.57 -6.68 -0.05 -5.59 -4.42 -1.79 -4.50 -7.68 -7.16 -5.39 -4.57 -5.32 -8.37 -6.55 -6.52 -8.41 -6.75 -3.39 -5.58 -7.97 -8.42 -9.11 -5.90 -8.43 -6.74 -6.29 -1.15 -8.35 -7.66 -7.87 -8.01 -6.61 -3.04 -9.08 -8.72 -2.59 -4.60 -3.37 -8.20 -0.93 -7.53 -3.85 -5.35 -7.44 -4.61 -7.25 -8.16 -8.44 -6.91 -8.39 0.03 -7.54 -6.05 -5.04 -7.85 -7.37 -8.53 -7.65 -9.35 -7.99 -8.27 -7.03 3.24 -4.82 -7.87 -7.18 -5.19 -8.71 -8.46 0.39 -5.95 -4.92 -7.38 -9.33 -4.05 -4.58 -4.74 -7.11 -6.39 -8.06 -7.61 -4.06 -4.70 -4.04 -7.28 -3.62 -6.89 -8.28 -2.61 -3.13 -8.76 -6.88 -6.62 -3.92 -8.24 -3.82 -0.91 -7.27 -7.82 -7.82 -7.14 -4.34 -7.99 -4.38 -5.67 -4.93 -6.21 -3.30 -4.22 -9.50 -6.71 -5.75 -6.76 -7.44 4.76 -7.00 -5.50 -7.48 -2.91 -8.52 -4.86 -8.09 -4.40 -7.82 -4.15 -7.03 -4.97 -4.71 -5.82 -1.23 -6.44 -3.95 -6.67 -2.81 -7.04 -2.39 -6.96 -6.24 -5.93 -3.56 -7.14 -7.97 -6.84 -6.34 0.24 -4.16 -8.59 -4.72 -8.66 -7.31 -6.74 -4.97 -6.07 -4.78 -6.31 -5.47 -3.42 -5.28 0.52
```

Comment: This problem seems rather usual. One could simply give a too general answer "Use any software for non-linear regression". Seriously, to be more concret can't you joint to your question an example of data (numerical, not graphical ) ?

Comment: That would not answer the question. There are many software packages that allow you to choose insane models. Ditto, a blackbox fit does not answer the question of if said fit is a MLE or not.

Comment: I added an example sample, rounded to 2 decimal places for character limit reasons.

Comment: @JJacquelin - This is not a 2d problem. This is a 1d problem. Analogous to the bog-standard case of finding the Normal distribution fitting a bunch of (1d) data points - where again your data is a list of 1d data points - but with a different distribution.

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, this model is known. It is either called the 3-parameter lognormal distribution, or sometimes TPLN (Three Parameter LogNormal).

It appears to be used in hydrologic analysis.

Unfortunately, [there is no global MLE](https://digitalcommons.fiu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1677&context=etd) (or rather, the global MLE is useless, converging towards the trivial case of infinite standard deviation, negative-infinite mean, and an offset of the smallest order statistic of the sample.)

There are however several local MLEs that appear to work well enough.

I can't answer the question of if there is a more appropriate model to use for this sort of data, however.

Answer (score 2):

We can rewrite the defining equation as
$$X = -C + e^{\mu + \sigma z}$$

So if $Q_1, Q_2, Q_3$ are the quartiles of $X$, with $z=-0.675$, $z=0$, $z=+0.675$, then
$$(Q_1+C)(Q_3+C)=(Q_2+C)^2$$
$$C = \frac{Q_2^2-Q_1 Q_3}{Q_1-2Q_2+Q_3}$$

The denominator here is a quantile-based measure of skewness, which should be positive for any dataset reasonably modeled by a shifted lognormal.

One approach using this is:

- Let $\hat{C}$ be the result of applying the above formula to the quartiles of the population.
- Let $\hat{\mu}$ be the corresponding MLE estimate for $\mu$, i.e. the mean of $\ln(X+\hat{C})$.
- Let $\hat{\sigma}$ be the corresponding MLE estimate for $\sigma$, i.e. the standard deviation of $\ln(X+\hat{C})$.

Another approach using this is:

- Let $\hat{C}$ be as above.
- Let $\hat{\mu}=\ln(Q_2+\hat{C})$.
- Let $\hat{\sigma}=\dfrac{1}{1.35}\ln\dfrac{Q_3+\hat{C}}{Q_1+\hat{C}}$
  where 1.35 is the interquartile range of the normal distribution.

The first approach is partially justified by MLE; the second approach matches the quartiles exactly. Both are simple and give reasonable starting points for further refinement.